# Inserting data to Mysql from Youtube api

Tags: php, mysql, api, youtube

I am trying to figure out how to insert all rows of video info from calls to the Youtube api using curl. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but no matter what I try I am only able to insert a single row.
Here is a simple example of one of the ways I have tried with a random playlist.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","...","...","...");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+id%2C+status&playlistId=PLU12uITxBEPHfZZRTIk96NduwU_8hT-Yo&maxResults=10&key={API KEY}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);

$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$result = json_decode($json_response, true);

foreach ($result['items'] as $page_info) {

$video_id = $page_info['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
$title = $page_info['snippet']['title'];

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO links (video_id, title) VALUES ('$video_id', '$title')");  

}
```

I also tried to create an array of everything and tried to dump it to sql. I figured I would still get the same 1 row result but I tried anyway.

```
$values = array();
foreach ($result['items'] as $page_info) {

$video_id = $page_info['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
$title = $page_info['snippet']['title'];

$values[] = "('$video_id', '$title')";
}
$query_values = implode(',', $values);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO links (video_id, title) VALUES $query_values");
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Turns out I had a problem with my table, I think it may have been corrupted or something. I created a new table and it solved my problem.

To anyone that may see this and is wanting/trying to learn how to use the Youtube api and insert data into your own database, the code above in the first box works fine as of right now.

Just change:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","...","...","...");
```

To your own db settings. Ex:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","Password","Database");
```

And add the values you want to insert such as $video_id, $title and update the query to use the new values.
Example:

```
$video_id = $page_info['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
$title = $page_info['snippet']['title'];
$description = $page_info['snippet']['description'];
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO links (video_id, title, description) VALUES ('$video_id', '$title', '$description')");
```

You also need to add your API key to your urls using key=.
Example:

```
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+id%2C+status&playlistId=PLU12uITxBEPHfZZRTIk96NduwU_8hT-Yo&maxResults=10&key=123456789123456789";
```

You can get your free api key by signing up here https://console.developers.google.com/ and then click library and select Youtube Data API.

To learn how to build urls so that you can query whetever data you want then this should be a good place to start. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests

Comment: Can you please post the output for var_dump($result['items']) ?

Comment: Here is print_r. I also posted it below. https://pastebin.com/88qZZ8t2

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the mysql query also in foreach . If you implode its converts just convert from array to string based on first parameter you passed to implode . Instead you do this.

```
    $values = array();
    foreach ($result['items'] as $page_info) {

    $video_id = $page_info['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
    $title = $page_info['snippet']['title'];
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO links (video_id, title) VALUES ('$video_id', '$title');
}
```

Comment: In the first example I do include the the sql query in the loop but it it only inserts the first row. I can see all the results in vardump but I only get the first row inserted which is why I am confused.

Comment: It is not possible. Please check your mysqli_query again. Since foreach iterates the your $result['items'].  if it is inserting only one then there might be only one record.

Comment: Here is print_r($result['items']); with my first example code if it helps. I only get the first row to insert and I get no errors. https://pastebin.com/88qZZ8t2

Comment: Please share the **json** format by encoding json_encode($result['times']);

Comment: I got it working. I created a new sample table and it works. I don't understand what is wrong with the other table though because I have no unique fields or anything and it is same as the new one. Thanks for your trying to help me anyway.